# regex - do not collect if formatted numbers before speific word anywhere in text string

Tags: python, regex

I do not want to match the regex if any formatted number, such as $1,000 appears anywhere before a specific word in the text string.

In this case the word to find is "expungement" - but only if there is NO formatted value before it.

So I would not want to match this string.

this is some initial text $11,000 recommends the expungement more text following

but this would be accepatable

this is some initial text expungement more text following

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pattern you can use is:

```
^[^\$]*(?!\$[0-9,]+)expungement
```

To explain:

1. ^ is start of string
2. [^$]* means match any character that is not '$', 0 or more times
3. (?!x) means negative lookup for x. If x is found in the line, the match is negated
4. \$[0-9,]+ is a literal dollar sign followed by any combination of digits and commas
5. Your desired string at the end

Comment: oops, not yet perfect.  what is we add text brefore the number?  this will not work 'dog cat $11,000 ... recommends the expungement'. so the ^ is probably not ok???

Comment: See edit, it now handles your extra condition